# In Django tests, can I capture SQL from separate threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a lot of Django tests (using unittest) that capture the SQL queries of some operation and make various assertions against them.

I'm now refactoring my code to introduce a `threading.Timer`, which executes some of the business logic in a callback after a certain amount of time. In my tests, I can force this callback to run instantly via, for example:

```
def test_foobar(self):
  with self.CaptureQueriesContext(self.connection) as captured:
    foo = MyServiceWithATimer()
    foo.execute()
    foo.timer.finished.set() # force the timer to complete immediately

  # make various assertions here
```

The problem is that `CaptureQueriesContext` now does not capture any of the SQL that ran in the `Timer`'s callback.

I've thought about alternative approaches such as not using `threading.Timer` at all, but these seem to require some sort of blocking `while True` event loop. Is there a way to make `CaptureQueriesContext` capture the SQL from child threads?